# In what scenario it makes sense to use multi db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm working on a side project of mine using rails api. The app is like a project manager which the structure is gonna be different based on the company type. For example a company which is doing production is different with a company that provides services. Does it make sense to use multi db in this case so based on the company type the users are gonna have different interface and structures?
Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Always, always go for the simplest solution first. There's no point architecting a multi db when you can have a single db with correct relations. Also, you might have trouble maintaining those multiple dbs on the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to use multiple databases when you're reaching the resource limits of a single database in your application. Of course this presumes you have also followed best practices along the way (efficient queries, effective caching strategies, etc.) Rails 6 has support for replicas which allow you to automatically separate your db writes from your db reads based on the HTTP verb. Beyond replicas, Rails 6 supports using a distinct database with its own replica for a custom collection of ActiveRecord models.

For more details I would recommend taking a look at the [Rails Guides on Multiple Databases](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html).